# Disk check on startup in 20.04

Tags: live-usb, 20.04

Downloaded 20.04 and created a USB using Rufus under windows 10.
A disk check seems to be triggered at each launch of the USB disk (using it as a live disk). Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Yes, easily. The instructions are on the screen during the check. You should be able to cancel it at any time during the check. You cannot, however, *permanently* disable it (it's a read-only fliesystem). The check was added to eliminate one of the most common causes of failed installs for new users - a corrupted or incomplete .iso download.

Comment: If I do not hit ctl-c immediately the check goes on for about five minutes. Very irritating, I think this must be a bug, nobody would do this on purpose. It even runs on persistent USB drives, they are not read only.

Comment: I think the problem is that cancelling the check might only happen after the current file has been processed, and since 20.04 contains a 2 GB `casper\filesystem.squashfs`, if you try to cancel while that file is validating,you're going to have to wait until those whole 2 GB have been read, which could indeed take minutes on a slow drive...

Comment: @Akeo:Sounds right. If I boot with fingers hovering above ctl and c and act the instant "Checking disks" appears, checking is cancelled. Congratulations on getting Rufus persistence working on 20.04. Now if you could just get rid of the try/install screen on persistent installs. As I recall it is just a matter of tweaking syslinux.cfg.

Comment: @Robert Levy: Bug Report filed, do you have anything to add? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1875548

Answer (score 3):

### Removing Disk Check on Persistent USB's

The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check.

The line `Checking disks: 0% complete` will still come up but **fsck** will not be run, nor will boot time be increased.

**mkusb** After the Persistent USB drive is created, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the Persistent menuentry thus:

  linux   ($root)/casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity fsck.mode=skip quiet splash persistent ---
- **Newer versions of mkusb already include this fix**.
- If you also wish to remove the **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen delete "maybe-ubiquity".

**UNetbootin** After creating the boot drive, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the first menuentry for (UEFI boot mode).
- Open syslinux.cfg as root and add `fsck.mode=skip` to the default menuentry for (BIOS boot mode).

**Rufus** After creating the boot drive, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the Default menuentry for (UEFI boot mode).
- Open /isolinux/txt.cfg as root and add `fsck.mode=skip` to the "Try Ubuntu without installing" menuentry, (for BIOS boot mode).

The **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen can be removed from BIOS boot by overwriting syslinux.cfg with:

```
default persistent
label persistent
  say Booting an Ubuntu Persistent session...
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash noprompt --
```

The **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen can be removed from Rufus UEFI boot by removing "maybe-ubiquity" from /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
.
.
.

**Edit 20200524:**
The above workaround is no longer needed.

This bug was fixed in the package 'casper - 1.447', as announced in:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1875548

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y casper
```

(I am still testing the fix, **It does not seem to be working yet**).

Comment: Thanks to brian-murray for fsck.mode=skip

Comment: If you're using cubic you can change the boot grub.cfg in the "boot" tab at the top, just before you actually create the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

### If you do not need this USB to install Ubuntu...

Consider doing a Full install to USB, It does not suffer from this irritating **disk check** problem when booting.

A Full install USB and a Persistent install USB both save data and installed programs after reboot.

**Comparison between Persistent and Full install USB**

**Advantages of a persistent install:**

1) You can use the persistent pendrive to install Ubuntu to another computer.

2) A persistent install takes up less space on the pendrive.

3) You can reset the pendrive by overwriting the old casper-rw file with a new one.

4) The install to pendrive takes less time.

**Advantages of a Full install:**

1) You can update and upgrade.

2) If you have problems or wish to modify, the solution is the same as with an internal install, (You can ask for help in these forums).

3) No ugly startup / install screen.

4) Better security, you can use full encryption

5) You can use proprietary drivers.

6) Hibernation works.

7) A persistent install is limited to a 4GB casper-rw and a 4GB home-rw persistence file, to get more persistence requires persistence partitions. Once casper-rw is full, the drive will not boot.

8) Faster boot, **no automatic disk checking**.

9) You can run VBox and use virtual machines.

Note that once booted, both methods run at about the same speed.

**Full Install Method**

One method for creating Full install USB: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step)